# Dynamic KML placemark name display possible?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am looking to have two names for a placemark, one displayed when the placemark is hovered over, and one when it is not hovered over. The only information I've been able to find is changing the style (icon type, color, opacity, scale) for a highlighted placemark style. Any suggestions? Is this possible?

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#custom_styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom icons to present a pseudo name (an image of the text you require) and another roll over pseudo name in the same manner.

This is called "styles for Highlighted Icons", to use it you would need to create and upload the two jpg images

```
nameImageOver.jpg
```

and

```
nameImageNormal.jpg
```

The kml would look like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Highlighted Icon</name>
    <description>Mouse over to see the swap</description>
    <Style id="highlightPlacemark">
      <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
        <href>http://www.yourserver.com/nameImageOver.jpg</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="normalPlacemark">
      <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://www.yourserver.com/nameImageNormal.jpg</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="exampleStyleMap">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#highlightPlacemark</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
      <styleUrl>#exampleStyleMap</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-122.0856545755255,37.42243077405461,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: The text, in my case, is dynamic for different placemarks. Your solution would work for static titles, or if you wanted to create an image for every possible combo. I'll mark this as correct, as it is a viable for some situations.

Comment: You can use something like gdlib to generate the images dynamically on a server. Google even have a free service that does this. Simply supply the text you require as a query. See http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/chart-type-for-text-with-outline?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using the Google Earth API. Not sure how this plays in with using KML...

```
// On mouse over - show name
google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'mouseover', function(event) {
    placemark.setName('My Placemark Label');
});
// On mouse out - hide (remove) name
google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'mouseout', function(event) {
    placemark.setName('');
});
```